# What is the difference between CFAutoRoot and CFRoot?

Tags: rooting

I wanted to "root" my Android phone. Therefore I went to the XDA forums to download the root package. I found two versions of it: CF Auto Root and CF root.

I thought one has to modify the kernel to obtain permenent "root" rights. Therefore it was justified that the CF Root package is nothing but a modified kernel. However, I didn't quite understand what the CF Auto Root does that is different? Isn't it also a modified kernel??

What does the author mean when he says this:

> CF-Root (non-Auto) are manually built rooted kernels and/or flashables
>   that usually provide more than “just root”. CF-Auto-Root is built on
>   an **automated** system that I am constantly improving that takes a stock
>   recovery image and returns an automated rooting packages. These
>   packages are designed to install and enable SuperSU on your device, so
>   apps can gain root access, and nothing more.

What does he refer as "automated" system??

Comment: Rooting does not necessarily involve a kernel change. Have you checked with the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info)? Many of our tags contain a quite comprehensive wiki. You can reach it e.g. by clicking on the "info" link while hovering your mouse over the tag below your question.